# figure out if QObject is a registered QML Type

Tags: qt, qml

i am registering lots of Types as QmlComponents via

```
qmlRegisterType<Service>("my.services", 1, 0, "Service");
```

Now I would like to traverse the object tree while getting qml-registered types ONLY.

```
void Service::traverse(QString &path, QObject *root) {
    if( <!root is registered qml type> ) { //<-- this piece im missing 
        return;
    }

    if(!path.isEmpty()) {
        path.append('.');
    };

    path.append(root->metaObject()->className());
    qDebug() << path;

    foreach(QObject *o, root->children()) {
        traverse(path, o);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can think of (without changing the types themselves) would be to use [`qmlEngine()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlEngine):

```
if (qmlEngine(root)) {
    return;
}
```

However, that will return true for any type created in QML.

To detect just your C++ types, you could give their type name a prefix (e.g. `QmlService`):

```
if (QString(root->metaObject()->className()).contains("Qml")) {
    return;
}
```

Though if you can do this, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just keep track of which types you register in a list or something and refer to it later. If you elaborate a bit about what you're trying to achieve, perhaps we can come up with better solutions.